# How to use function inside while statement to get associative array value?

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I'm trying to figure out how to get value from associative array by putting a function inside a while statement?

```
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $message = $row["message"];
  $reply = $row["reply"];

   $object->gets("'.$message.'", function ($obj) {
                $obj->posts("'.$reply.'");
            });

  }
```

Obviously that code wont work because the variable `$reply` needs to be initialized inside the function to work. How can I do this procedural style? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your'e asking, but if you need the `$reply` variable within the scope of your function, you can do `function ($ob) use ($reply) { ...`

Comment: Why $reply var must be initialized inside the function to work?

Comment: @MilanG: What I mean is that the $reply wont posts inside the function if it is not initialized.

Comment: Usages like `"'.$message.'"` look very fishy - are you sure on what you construct there? In contrast to `$message` alone without apostrophes and dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to be able to access the `$reply` value inside your function?

In order to get the variable within the scope of the function do following :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $message = $row["message"];
  $reply = $row["reply"];

   $object->gets("'.$message.'", function ($obj) use ($reply) {
                $obj->posts("'.$reply.'");
            });

  }
```